# Django printing multiple form fields

Tags: django, django-forms

Hello I'm very new to django and python and would ppreciate if you could help me out.
I want to create 2 fields, namely password and confirm password but the webpage renders 2 sets of each.

this is the forms.py code:

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(label="", widget= forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Email Address'}))
    first_name = forms.CharField(label="",widget= forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder': 'First Name'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(label="",widget= forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Last Name'}))
    ph_number = forms.CharField(label="",widget= forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Phone Mumber'}))
    password_1 = forms.CharField(label="",widget= forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Password 1'}))
    password_2 = forms.CharField(label="",widget= forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Password 2'}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 
                'first_name',
                'last_name',
                'email', 
                'ph_number', 
                'password_1', 
                'password_2'
                ) 
        
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'User Name'
        self.fields['username'].label = ''
        self.fields['username'].help_text = '<span class="form-text text-muted"><small>Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.</small></span>'

        self.fields['ph_number'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['ph_number'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Phone Number'
        self.fields['ph_number'].label = ''
        self.fields['ph_number'].help_text = '<span class="form-text text-muted small"><small>Your number can\'t be more than 10 digits.</small><small>Your phone number is too short</small></span>'

        self.fields['password_1'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password_1'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Password'
        self.fields['password_1'].label = ''
        self.fields['password_1'].help_text = '<ul class="form-text text-muted small"><li>Your password can\'t be too similar to your other personal information.</li><li>Your password must contain at least 8 characters.</li><li>Your password can\'t be a commonly used password.</li><li>Your password can\'t be entirely numeric.</li></ul>'

        self.fields['password_2'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password_2'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Confirm Password'
        self.fields['password_2'].label = ''
        self.fields['password_2'].help_text = '<span class="form-text text-muted"><small>Enter the same password as before, for verification.</small></span>'
```

The output looks like this:
[image]

base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Django CRM</title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    {% include 'navbar.html'%}
    <div class="Container">
      <br />
        {% if messages %} 
          {% for message in messages %}
              <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                {{message}}
                <button
                  type="button"
                  class="btn-close"
                  data-bs-dismiss="alert"
                  aria-label="Close"
                ></button>
              </div>
            {% endfor %} 
        {% endif %} 
      {% block content %} 
      {% endblock %}
    </div>

    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

home.html code:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} 

{% block content %}

{% if user.is_authenticated%}
<h1>Hello</h1>

{% else %}
<div class="col-md-6 offset-md-5">
  <br />
  <h1>Login</h1>
  <br />
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 offset-md-4">{% include 'forms.html' %}</div>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

register.html code:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} 
{% block content %}


<div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <br/>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">

<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ form.as_p }}

    <br/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Register</button>
</form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: add frontend section of your code as well, maybe thats where the problem is

Comment: @scaryhamid I have included the front end code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are overriding the `UserCreationForm` wrong. the correct code would be something like this:

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(label="", widget= forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Email Address'}))
    first_name = forms.CharField(label="",widget= forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder': 'First Name'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(label="",widget= forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Last Name'}))
    ph_number = forms.CharField(label="",widget= forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Phone Mumber'}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(label="",widget= forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Password 1'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(label="",widget= forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Password 2'}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 
                'first_name',
                'last_name',
                'email', 
                'ph_number', 
                'password1', 
                'password2'
                ) 
        .
        .
        . 
        # rest of the code
```

make sure to read the classes that you are using and abstracting from. there is no `password_1` or `password_2` in `UserCreationForm`.